# Exact Search in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui-datatable

I want to see my exact keyword  search in data table. I have a gender column wheres values are male,female and others when I am searching male then show  male and female both but I want to see male only.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable();
    oTable.fnFilter( "^" + TERM + "$", COLUMN , true);
});
```

Comment: Ok. Do you have a specific issue with this code, if so please give details.

Comment: i want  to search employe  from employee table with gender wise.... when  i am searching with male then male and female both show. i want to see male only when write male in search box.